# If $f$ differentiable at $a$, $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$, what is the exact argument that allows us to say $f'(a) \geq 0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The following is a problem from Ch. 11 in Spivak's Calculus:

> 60. (a) Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$. Prove that if the minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is at $a$, than $f'(a) \geq 0$, and if
>     it is at $b$, than $f'(b) \leq 0$

Proof

Let $x \in (a,b)$.

Then since $a$ is a minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$, we have that $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$.

Therefore,

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$$

$f$ is differentiable at $a$ by assumption. Therefore,

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$$

At this point we need to conclude that $f'(a) \geq 0$. My question is: what is the exact argument that allows us to conclude this?

**Is the argument simply that because $f$ is differentiable at $a$, we know that the limits defining the derivative from above and below at $a$ must be equal. So since the limit from above is $\geq 0$, the limit from below must be as well, and therefore $f'(a) \geq 0$ as well.**

In graph to the right below, with the extra information that $a$ is a minimum also on an interval $(a-\delta, a]$, we could conclude that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \leq 0$$

We can see from the graph that in fact $f'(a)=0$.

We would have

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \leq 0$$

So we would be able to say that $0 \leq f'(a) \leq 0$

[image]

Comment: You have a typo in the title: in the conclusion it must be greater or equal than $0$, not than $a$.

Comment: By hypothesis $f$ is differentiable at $a$, i.e. $$f'(a)= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ since it is a limit of a non-negative quantity, it must be non-negative.

Comment: It's non-negative for the $x \to a^+$ limit. For the $x \to a^-$ limit it can be non-positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Proof
>
> Let $x\in(a,b)$.
>
> Then since $a$ is a minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$, we have that $\dfrac{f(x)−f(a)}{x−a}\geq0$.
>
> Therefore,
> $$\lim_{x\to a^{+}}\frac{f(x)−f(a)}{x−a}\geq0$$

And you're done!

Modulo some minor inaccuracies in wording (for example, I'd rather say that "since the minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is at $a$", as it was in the statement of the problem), this is all you needed to do.

You can't set up "$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a^{-}}\frac{f(x)−f(a)}{x−a}$" here, as the function $f$ is only defined on $[a,b]$, and therefore $f(x)$ for $x$ to the left of $a$ doesn't make sense.

When we say that a function is differentiable on a closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$, by definition it means that the usual derivative exists for all interior points $x\in(a,b)$, but the derivative at $a$ is understood as the right-sided derivative and the derivative at $b$ is understood as the left-sided derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite the proof as follows:

> Let $x \in (a,b)$.
>
> Then since $a$ is a minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$, we have that $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$.
>
> Therefore,
> $$\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$$
>
> $f$ is differentiable at $a$ by assumption. Therefore,
> $$f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq 0$$

---

The only step we changed was the end.  Specifically, this just uses the fact that if $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to c} g(x) = \lim_{x\to c^+} g(x)$

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using that the function is defined on $[a,b]$. So, the lower limit is not defined, and the derivative at $a$ is just given by the upper limit. So $f’(a)\geq0$ by what you have already shown, and it does not have to equal $0$.

Comment: I used that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ by assumption. Therefore $f$ is continuous at $a$, and hence defined at $a$.

Comment: Note it never says $f$ is defined only on $[a,b]$, but rather that it's differentiable on $[a,b]$.  Without knowing how Spivak defined differentiability on a set, it's perhaps ambiguous, allowing for the possibility that it's only defined on $[a,b]$, but it's definitely not as strong as you're making it out to be.

Comment: Let me rephrase: if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, which means that $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists, then $f$ is continuous at $a$. If $f$ is continuous at $a$ then it is defined at $a$. Is this correct?